# какой тип у этого языка?

Tags: компиляция

Извините за глупый вопрос.
Нашел такой проект - https://github.com/xzripper/LMathLang/
Как я подразумеваю, это язык.
Но не могу понять, компилируем, интерпретируемый, транспилируемый, т.д.
Как я понял, точно не компилируемый.
Что это за тип?

Comment: Судя по lua внутри - интерпретируемый

Comment: из того, что я вижу - интерпретатор.

Comment: Компилируемый, интерпретируемый, транспилируемый - это не тип языка, а способ подготовки/исполнения кода на этом языке. Вообще технически ничего не мешает написать компилятор для языка, традиционно считающегося интерпретируемым, или наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Это улучшенный вариант языка MathLang перенесенный в LUA. А сам MathLang это сильный язык математики с очень простым синтаксисом в Pyton. Это все.

Comment: серьезно, я спросил какой тип языка